# What is the purpose of the PowerPC instruction `bcctr`?

Tags: assembly, powerpc, instruction-set

I'm new to the PowerPC architecture and I'm looking at some disassembled code with the `bcctr` instruction. Although the manual specifies how the `bcctr` instruction works, it doesn't explain what it typically would be used for.
Can you come up with examples of such uses, and detail what rôle the `ctr` register plays?
My best guess is that it is used for indirect branches (e.g. to implement calls to function pointers or vtables), but the purpose of

> "decrement `ctr` register and then branch to `ctr`"

is not at all clear to me. The dual use of the register as a counter and as a destination address is especially confusing.

Comment: I think it's just a useful alternative to `bclr`, so you can keep whatever address is in `LR` and have an alternate destination address for a conditional branch in `CTR` (you obviously don't use the decrement in this context). See: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.10/10.09/PowerPCAssembly/index.html

Comment: Yes, the decrement function is probably a side-effect of instruction encoding, hard to imagine a case where that would be useful.

Comment: The manual suggests it's used for computed `goto`, `switch`-statements. Might save an instruction or two if cleverly used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `bcctr` (and its unconditional variant, `bctr`) is generally used for branches to a function pointer.

The Power ISA instruction set has two instructions¹ that are available for branching to an address in a register: `blr`  (branch to link register) and `bctr` (branch to counter register). Using `bctr` means we can preserve the link register.

In this case, there's nothing special about using the ctr register here - it's just the address that we branch to. There'll be a `mtctr` instruction earlier in the stream, where we load an address into the ctr register.

You'll probably see `bctrl` used too: this sets the link register to the current address + 4, then does a branch to the counter. This allows the call (through the function pointer) to return, by branching back to the link register.

¹: in non-privileged mode, at least

Comment: Question I haven't researched yet: Do modern POWER / PowerPC chips maintain a return-address predictor stack and assume that `blr` is a return to the last branch that set LR?  In that case you'd definitely want (your compiler) to use `bctr` for branches that *aren't* returns, like `switch` jump tables within a function, or tailcalling a function pointer.  Interesting that PPC doesn't have a branch-to-GPR for an arbitrary register; most ISAs do have that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the actual implementation of branch prediction on specific POWER processors, but there should be no difference between `blr` and `bctr` in terms of predictability. A fairly straightforward prediction would simply be based on previous branch history for that specific instruction, regardless of source. For switch jump tables, a `b` or `bc` would be best, as the branch target it probably represent-able as an immediate. For tail recursion, `blr` is fine, just that you have the top-level caller's value still in `lr` (simply by not overwriting it).

Comment: In an implementation that tries to predict call/return specially (like all modern x86, and modern ARM CPUs), using `blr` might always predict as jumping to the instruction after the most recent `bl` or call-like instruction.  (Because the front-end keeps a call-stack predictor in hardware separate from whatever software *actually* does, because software normally matches call with ret).  See [Return address prediction stack buffer vs stack-stored return address?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22442766) - x86 has been doing this since PPro in 1995.

Answer (score 4):

looking at the POWER ISA, I see:

bcctr = Branch Conditional to Count Register

Usage:
bcctr B0, BI, BH

Algorithm:

```
cond_ok <- BO_0 | (CR_{BI+32} ≡ BO 1 )
if cond_ok then NIA <- {iea} CTR_{0:61} || 0b00
if LK then LR <- {iea} CIA + 4
```

BI+32 specifies the Condition Register bit to be tested.
The BO field is used to resolve the branch as described
in Figure 44. The BH field is used as described in
Figure 46.
The branch target address is CTR 0:61 || 0b00, with the high-order 32 bits of the branch target address set to 0 in 32-bit mode. If LK=1 then the effective address of the instruction following the Branch instruction is placed into the Link Register.
If the “decrement and test CTR” option is specified (BO 2 =0), the  instruction form is invalid.

Source: [Power ISA Version 2.07](https://web.archive.org/web/20160924100612/https://www.power.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/PowerISA_V2.07_PUBLIC.pdf)